# the difference between the drupal login "block" and mysite/user/login

Tags: users

I trying to understand the difference between the default Drupal 7 login block and the login provided at mysite/user/login.

From my own understanding, it would appear that the default login block provided by Drupal 7 only logs you into the web interface and the login provided at mysite/user/login is a page provided for you to login through your website.

I have come to this conclusion because if I log out of the web interface and try to login at user/login, nothing happens (I enter my credentials, but nothing happens).

This is my understanding.

If my understanding is wrong, I would appreciate it if someone could please correct me. If I am correct, could someone please provide a good tutorial that teaches one how to use the login page to validate a user and "transfer" the user to a validated state?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such difference. Both forms provide the same input fields and use the same validation and submit handlers. The one is generated by [user_login()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login/7), the other is generated by [user_login_block()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login_block/7).

Comment: Thank you Oswald for clearing that up. If there is no such difference, then why can't log in to the Drupal 7 web interface through mysite/user/login? I have a Drupal 7 multi-site setup, some have that said that might affect things.